# Forcing a term/taxonomy on all posts of CPT

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT - 'Events' with 400+ posts [with no terms in the custom taxonomy (tax_category) selected] in them, as I recently imported those posts.

Now, I've created a URL structure where I need to have some term of tax_category assigned to each post. So, is there any way with which I can assign a term from tax_category (say 'New Gigs') to all posts of the Events cpt?

While searching I also found the following code, but am confused of how can I modify it suit my need or it even is the solution am looking for? -

```
function mfields_set_default_object_terms( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'post_tag' => array( 'taco', 'banana' ),
            'monkey-faces' => array( 'see-no-evil' ),
            );
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type );
        foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
            if ( empty( $terms ) && array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $defaults ) ) {
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $defaults[$taxonomy], $taxonomy );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'mfields_set_default_object_terms', 100, 2 );
```

Code Source - http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function custom_set_term_to_post(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        );
    $all_posts = get_posts();
    foreach ($all_posts as $key => $post) {
        $tag_name = 'post_tag'; // required tag name
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $tag_name, array("fields" => "ids"));
        if (!empty($term_list)) {
            // there is already tags; need not do anything
            continue;
        }
        $tag = array( 23 ); // required tag ID to assign
        wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $tag, $tag_name );
    }
}
```

This function scans all posts of post type `post` and check if it has any tag or not. If no any tag is assigned, then required tag is assigned. Here tag name is `post_tag`. And required tag item is of id `23`. Replace it with your value.
Make sure this function only run once. Just for current purpose. Dont leave it in the theme. :-)